# Unable to cross compile with cmake 2.8

Tags: makefile, cmake, arm, cross-compiling

I have the following build structure:

```
/blah/3rdparty/yang
/blah/3rdparty/Makefile
/blah/3rdparty/toolchain.cmake
/blah/3rdparty/yang/libyang-0.14.78
```

And I have this mockup `Makefile` that I am trying to invoke the underlaying cmake

```
all: prep

prep:
        cd libyang-0.14.78 ; \
        cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../toolchain.cmake \
        -DENABLE_BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
        -DENABLE_VALGRIND_TESTS=OFF \
        -DPCRE_LIBRARY=/blah/lib/lipcre.so \
        -DPCRE_INCLUDE_DIR=/blah/include \
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:String="Release"
```

However no matter what I do, the `cmake` won't pick up the settings in `toolchain.cmake` I'm passing to it.

The `toolchain.cmake`:

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-openwrt-linux-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-openwrt-linux-gcc)
SET(host arm-linux)
SET(SYSROOT /blah/tools/armv7-openwrt-linux-gnu-uClibc-0.9.33.2)
SET(CMAKE_SYSROOT ${SYSROOT})
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${SYSROOT})
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

When I go check which executables it is using, all i see is the host executables, and not from my toolchain... This is what cmake prints out when I use the `-LAH` option to it...

```
// Path to a program.
CMAKE_AR:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/ar
// C compiler.
CMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/cc
// Path to a program.
CMAKE_LINKER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/ld
```

CMake version is `2.8.12.2` and I can't upgrade the version.

Questions:

- If I **absolutely** need to to it this way, what is the proper way to invoke `cmake` from a `Makefile`?
- Am I invoking the `prep` correctly? It seems that `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` or the rest of the settings never carried over.
- Is my `toolchain.cmake` correct?

Comment: Have you tried to clear build directory before calling `cmake`? If you have built the project in this directory without toolchain before, then CMake may ignore toolchain parameter in the next invocations.

Comment: Yes. I had been trying various ways for the past 2 days with no success. I thought perhaps CMake 2.8 was ignoring the file, but reading on the web suggests that it should take it via `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`... But everything from the log shows that is not using the compiler I ask for in the `toolchain.cmake` file. So I am lost...

Comment: Have you tried these steps outside of the `Makefile`? And you are giving `cmake` a directory argument, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up abandoning using of `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE`, turns out you can pass everything directly to it. Here is the end result that works in my `Makefile` that calls `cmake`:

```
configure:
        cd libyang-0.14.78; \
rm -rf build; mkdir -p build; cd build; \
cmake \
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Linux \
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=arm \
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=arm-openwrt-linux-gcc \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$(MY_TOOLCHAIN) \
-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=$(MY_TOOLCHAIN) \
-DPCRE_LIBRARY=$(MY_TOOLCHAIN)/lib/libpcre.so \
-DPCRE_INCLUDE_DIR=$(MY_TOOLCHAIN)/include \
-DENABLE_BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
-DENABLE_VALGRIND_TESTS=OFF \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:String="Release" .. > config.log;
```

I am not sure if `cmake` 2.8.12 doesn't support `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` or what not, but since it works I don't care anymore. :P